# Custom user option input in Select2 4.x?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

There is a way to add a custom user input in Select2 without using the `tags` mode.

This is, create a custom select input preserving the select style, without that inline-block little tags.

Also, I found a lot of answers using AJAX and other **out of topic** things in which none was a **solution** to my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a easy way to implement this functionality:

```
tags: true // let users input his/her own value
multiple: false // forces the select to keep a true select style
```

---

**Working fiddle (2016-10-29):**

```js
$("select").select2({
  multiple: false,
  tags: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/odahcam/q096tskj/4/">Original Fiddle by @odahcam</a>
</p>

<select style="width:100%">
  <option>story</option>
  <option>bug</option>
  <option>task</option>
</select>
```